# How to reduce apk size built with Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: android, visual-studio, deployment, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making a Xamarin Forms application with a Portable Class Library (PCL).

I've created an application with two screens. When the .apk is generated, I noted it's too heavy. I've seen that's due to the [Linker](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/) / [Linking process](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/).

The steps I have done to generate the .apk are:

1. Build configuration: Release - Any CPU
2. Bluid --> Clean Solution
3. Build --> Build Solution
4. In solution explorer, I select the Android (Droid) project
5. Build --> Export Android Package (.apk)
6. The apk package is in project_forder/bin/Release/project-name.Droid-Signed.apk

Result is a package about 17 MB.

The steps I have done trying to reduce size are:

1. Right click over Android (Droid) project
2. Click "Properties" option
3. Tab "Android Options"
4. Then "Linker" tab
5. In the Linking combo, I select Sdk Assemblies Only
6. And I repeat the steps to generate the apk.

When Linking combo I select:

- Sdk Assembles only: the size of the apk is the same (17 MB)
- Sdk and User Assembles: the size decrease (13 MB), but I think it is too much. Also, when installing package in mobile and running application, it stops immediately. I think this is related to some dependency not being included.

Notes:

- I haven't set image resources yet.
- I included a dependency ZXing from NuGet.

**EDIT:**

I unziped the apk, and its structure is:

- /assemblies/ (10.8 MB, with a lot of .dll's)
- /lib/armeabi/ (2.84 MB, with libmonodroid.so and libmonosgen-2.0.so)
- /lib/armeabi-v7a/ (2.80 MB, with libmonodroid.so and libmonosgen-2.0.so)
- /lib/x86/ (3.41 MB, with libmonodroid.so and libmonosgen-2.0.so)
- /META-INF/ (100 KB)
- /res/ (1.02 MB)
- AndroidManifest.xml (4 KB)
- classes.dex (2.5 MB)
- environment (1 KB)
- NOTICE (1 KB)
- resources.arsc (241 KB)
- typemap.jm (332 KB)
- typemap.mj (381 KB)

One solution is creating a .apk for each architecture. In this case, each .apk takes 13-14 MB, where into the lib folder only includes the libmonodroid.so and libmonosgen-2.0.so for specific architecture. I still thinking that's too much 14 MB.

How can I know which files in assembles folder may be omitted?

I heard (by a friend), that when publishing a single .apk on Google Play, if a apk package has the libraries for all architectures (arm, x86, etc.) and the package takes 17 MB, when the user downloads the app, Google Play makes an .apk with specific mobile user characteristics (14 MB). Is it true? If so, publishing an 17 MB .apk wouldn't be a problem.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415053/please-help-reducing-xamarin-android-apk-size) is what my question talks about, but it doesn't clarify which assembles I can omit or what to do to exclude them. I don't think Opening/unziping .apk file and removing libraries and assembles is a polite solution.

Comment: I would recommend following tiny sunlight's advice of unpacking your .apk and viewing what is so large inside of it. You can simply extract the .apk and then use a tool like WinDirStat on Windows(https://windirstat.info/) or Disk Inventory X on Mac(http://www.derlien.com/)

Comment: Which ABI are you including in your APK? As 13MB for the NDK-based Mono runtime plus user assembly sounds about right... Checkout my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33416893/4984832

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Please help reducing Xamarin.Android apk size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415053/please-help-reducing-xamarin-android-apk-size)

Comment: @JonDouglas as you suggested me, I used the WinDirStat tool to see which files are the heaviest. I've unziped the apk package and I see that only "lib" folder takes 9 MB (3 MB for each arch: x86, armeabi and armeabi-v7a).

Comment: @SushiHangover I have read your answer. I'm including the same architectures and the same libs as you specified and the result is the same size. Also, I had read the Xamarin article [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/application_package_sizes/) They reduced the apk size magically 15 to 4 MB.

Comment: @stivex Are you asking about `Linking` in release distributions? If so, yes, applying 'Linking` to just the .Net/Mono framework (or the entire app) can and will reduce the final apk size. Note: That linking can cause stray bugs if the class is not seen as used, but really is, i.e. If you are using "reflection" the linker can not determine you really want that class to remain and will remove it, in these cases you need to ref/flag the class to avoid this

Comment: @SushiHangover yes, I have tried to reduce the apk using Linking, but I can't achieve reduce the size significantly. An application with two screens without images, 14 MB is too heavy to download from Google Play. Perhaps, I'm leaving some steps. I don't understand why the Linking process doesn't reduce significantly the apk size. Perhaps I have to define some tags or declarations into my code or project?

Answer (score 1):

You can unzip the apk to look up which part make it so large.And you can crack the apk to see the packages it contains.