# Is there anyway to reduce android native app size in xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working with VS2015 to develop android native app using xamarin. I have only 3 user controls(2 textbox,1 button). When i am deploying the application, it is showing the size "**9.2MB**" ?

**Note**: I am getting this size after using "linker" and "packaging" option which is given in [reduce app size](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/application_package_sizes/)

Comment: 9.2MB on your release build is acceptable while using Xamarin because of the added dlls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Please help reducing Xamarin.Android apk size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415053/please-help-reducing-xamarin-android-apk-size)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple options left.

- Learn and use ProGuard
- Minimize your resources. Especially image resources like png or jpg files tend to make a huge impact on the final apk size.
- Check the ABIs you are building for. Consider to build one apk for each ABI.
- Check the size of your assets.

Answer (score 0):

We have a guide here which explains what the apk file consists of when building with Xamarin Android:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/application_package_sizes/

Making sure you are using the linker is the best way to reduce the apk size as it removes anything your app is not utilising at runtime.

Release apk sizes are larger due to the inclusion of the Mono runtime. When you are debugging, the app will use the shared Mono runtime which is installed to the device and is not included in your apk (see Fast Assembly Deployment in the above link).

You can potentially reduce the resulting size by enabling progaurd:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/#ProGuard

Additional resources:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/
http://motzcod.es/post/112072508362/how-to-keep-your-android-app-size-down