# How can reduce apk size in xamarin platform

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I tried to build release apk for xamarin form **hello world** project. i tried all what xamarin document suggest for reduce the apk size but still it 14mb. I tried to build apk for both shared and pcl project but no luck 
[xamarin doc](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/)

Could you please help some one and guide me for how can i reduce the android apk size. I used visual studio 2015 for development

Comment: @SushiHangover But still that question don't have answer

Comment: I linked the wrong Q/A, the answer is an apk size of 14MB is correct, a `Xamarin.Android`-based NDK app includes the Mono runtime/VM so you can run C#/CIL code, nothing you can do about that:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415053/please-help-reducing-xamarin-android-apk-size/33416893#33416893

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/application_package_sizes/

Comment: @SushiHangover What you tell? we cannot reduce the apk size below 14mb?

Comment: Each NDK-based Mono `ABI` takes between 3 to 3.5MB, so you can create an `.APK` per `ABI` and publish multiple APKs to the App store... In release mode, enabling Proguard, enable CIL linking all assemblies and publishing one APK per ABI, you will end up with an APK size of about 11.3MB for an `Xamarin.Android`/`Xamarin.Forms`-based HelloWorld app

Comment: @SushiHangover so we can not create the app for below 11.38 MB. Am i right?

Comment: Correct, for a `Xamarin.Forms` based single-ABI `.APK`, that would be the min. size.