# I can't reduce apk size using proguard on xamarin.android

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, proguard

I heard that when I enable **Enable proguard** the apk size is reduced, but I did that, created the apk and its size is the same that it was before I enabled this option...
My proguard.conf has just a line:

**-ignorewarnings**

Comment: 1) Proguard only works against the **Java-based** libraries in your app. 2) Have you enabled the Mono/CIL Linker to strip the unused code from the .Net frameworks?

Comment: I choosed **Sdk assemblies only** on linker dropdown...The app size was reduced a half...But it has 34 mb now...for me it's big...

Comment: It really depends upon a number of factors, each arch type included will add ~3MB, how many libraries are included, how much of that code is left by the linker, how many Java libs are included, the sizes of your images/assets, etc... Fine tuning the size will require enabling the Linker for all code (not just Framework SDK) with (assumably) a custom Linker config file, custom Proguard configs, etc. Possibly creating multiple APKs that break the arch types into separate APKs and also producing multiple APKs based on asset resolution. 34MB is not a bad start for an Xamarin-based app.

Comment: I think the size is not interesting for google play users

Comment: It really depends upon the type/purpose/feature-set of app and its intended audience. There certainly are larger Java-based main-stream APKs in the Play store and there are smaller. Due the inclusion of the Mono runtime within a Xamarin-based app, there will always be a size penalty there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415053/please-help-reducing-xamarin-android-apk-size/33416893#33416893 Again, you need to determine what is making up that 34MB and work backwards on custom a Linker file, custom Proguard, producing  multiple arch-based APKS, etc...

Comment: 34mb.. its xamarin so its not big at all. Go pure native or pay with size and speed for using the framework.

Comment: Yeah, I think u r right...for a xamarin app, it's not big....